# What is this black insect (wasp-like?) South America?

Tags: entomology, species-identification

I live in the Pacific coast of South America. Seems to have two wings, like a wasp's. The "tail" is a bit bulky but is only connected to the rest of the body by a thin part. It's black overall. The antennae in the photo are downwards but they just spring normally to the front...
 [image: the bug]

Comment: The Evaniidae, also known as the ensign wasps or hatchet wasps

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually I took photoshop to help me find this little guy, [Ensign Wasp(Evaniidae)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaniidae)

[Google Images:](https://6legs2many.wordpress.com/tag/parasitoid-wasps/)

---

[image]

### My Photoshop research:

[image]

[image]

Comment: How did you do that? Photoshop search?

Comment: Np, I actually used Photoshop to identify the color of it's eyes and Antenna. It was quite clear it was wasp after that.

Comment: @jleeothon: Welcome to Biology SE, Can you mark as answer if this is what you were looking for?